# How to use $resource in Angular service

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-services

Hello I need to find/update users from a mongodb collections via angular.
And I need to find them by _id and by username, so I created a service like this:

```
// Users service used for communicating with the users REST endpoint
angular.module('users').factory('Users', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('users/:id', {}, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

And on Express I have the relative API route:

```
app.route('/users/:userId').put(users.update);
```

Now, suppose I have another express route like this to check username availability:

```
app.route('/users/:username').get(users.check);
```

How can I integrate this last one in the same angular service?

UPDATE:
Solved with this, is it right?

```
angular.module('users').factory('Users', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return {
            byId: $resource('users/:id', {}, {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            }),
            byUsername: $resource('users/:username', {}, {
            })
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: How do you differentiate it on express side, both routes look same to me. Is the second route always used to check availability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to do something like this?

Angular service:

```
angular.module('users').factory('Users', function($resource) {
var resource = $resource('users/:byAttr/:id', {}, {
    update: {
        method: 'PUT',
        isArray: false,
        cache: false
    }
});
return {
    updateById: function (id) {
        resource.update({id: id, byAttr: 'id'});
    },
    updateByName: function (username) {
        resource.update({username: username, byAttr: 'username'});
    },
}
```

});

Routes:

```
app.route('/users/id/:userId').put(users.update);
app.route('/users/user/:username').get(users.check);
```